# Openshift Failed to create the following private endpoints

Tags: phpmyadmin, openshift

I'm using a custom cartridge for having phpmyadmin 4 on openshift: https://github.com/arielscarpinelli/openshift-scalable-phpmyadmin

It was working but today it ceased to work; so I removed it but when I try to reinstall it again I get the following error:

> Unexpected error: Failed to create the following private endpoints due
>   to existing process bindings:
>   OPENSHIFT_PHPMYADMIN_IP(8081)=127.12.146.132;

I restarted my app but it did not help...any hint?

Comment: Somehow is working again without I had to do anything...weird

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue please follow the below step.
1. Login in your account through putty.
2. Find the running process associated with mysql.
   ps -ef|grep mysql
3. Kill all the process by using kill -9 
4. Then try to restart the server.